# runs fine on IDE but gives Runtime Error(SIGSEGV) on submitting

Tags: c

https://www.codechef.com/problems/CLEANUP/

After a long and successful day of preparing food for the banquet, it is time to clean up. There is a list of n jobs to do before the kitchen can be closed for the night. These jobs are indexed from 1 to n.

Most of the cooks have already left and only the Chef and his assistant are left to clean up. Thankfully, some of the cooks took care of some of the jobs before they left so only a subset of the n jobs remain. The Chef and his assistant divide up the remaining jobs in the following manner. The Chef takes the unfinished job with least index, the assistant takes the unfinished job with the second least index, the Chef takes the unfinished job with the third least index, etc. That is, if the unfinished jobs were listed in increasing order of their index then the Chef would take every other one starting with the first job in the list and the assistant would take every other one starting with the second job on in the list.

The cooks logged which jobs they finished before they left. Unfortunately, these jobs were not recorded in any particular order. Given an unsorted list
of finished jobs, you are to determine which jobs the Chef must complete and which jobs his assitant must complete before closing the kitchen for the
evening.
Input

The first line contains a single integer T ≤ 50 indicating the number of test cases to follow. Each test case consists of two lines. The first line contains two numbers n,m satisfying 0 ≤ m ≤ n ≤ 1000. Here, n is the total number of jobs that must be completed before closing and m is the number of jobs that have already been completed. The second line contains a list of m distinct integers between 1 and n. These are the indices of the jobs that have already been completed. Consecutive integers are separated by a single space.
Output

The output for each test case consists of two lines. The first line is a list of the indices of the jobs assigned to the Chef. The second line is a list of the indices of the jobs assigned to his assistant. Both lists must appear in increasing order of indices and consecutive integers should be separated by a single space. If either the Chef or the assistant is not assigned any jobs, then their corresponding line should be blank.
Example

Input:

```
3
6 3
2 4 1
3 2
3 2
8 2
3 8
```

Output:

```
3 6
5
1

1 4 6
2 5 7
```

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int t=0,n=0,m=0,i=0,count=0,val=0,j=0;
    int arr[100]={0};
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        scanf("%d",&m);
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
           scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }

        val=0;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
               count=0;
             for(j=0;j<m;j++)
             {
                 if(i==arr[j])
                 {
                     count=1;
                     break;
                 }
             }
             if(count==0)
             {
                 val=val+1;
                 if(val%2!=0)
                 printf("%d ",i);
             }
        }
        printf("\n");
        val=0;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
               count=0;
             for(j=0;j<m;j++)
             {
                 if(i==arr[j])
                 {
                     count=1;
                     break;
                 }
             }
             if(count==0)
             {
                 val=val+1;
                 if(val%2==0&&val!=0)
                 printf("%d ",i);
             }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

runs fine on IDE but gives 
Runtime Error(SIGSEGV) on submitting .. pls help

Comment: what is so _cool_ with variable names being `a`, `b`, `c`, `m`, `n`. It makes very hard to understand the code written by someone else, you know?

Comment: t is test case,&& Here, n is the total number of jobs that must be completed before closing and m is the number of jobs that have already been completed.variale names are taken as per given in question.
i,j is for loop;

Comment: Use proper variable names and add comments. 4 weeks rom now, you will not be able to understand that yourself anymore, even less someone else. An give more details about the error. Run that in a debugger.

Comment: ok.. i will surely do it from next time ...

Comment: @amber,  adding the code documentation in some comment fixes nothing.  comment the code,  use meaningful names for variables.   When asking for input from the user, always display a prompt, so the user knows what to input.   when calling scanf(), always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: Why have any scanf() calls.  the current status is known at the time the cook and helper begin cleanup.  Therefore, a table containing a list of all the cleanup jobs and notations of which job is already finished would be a reasonable item.  For realistic usage, the table should probably be in a separate file (the we can assume was updated by each of the other helpers as they performed the cleanup jobs)

Comment: a good programmer is an exceeding lazy person.  They write simple applications, that do not require the user to perform lots of typing nor force the user to memorize all the inputs needed by a program.   I.E.  use inline comments that tell a new programmer what is going on and the meaning of things, like variables.  AND output prompts to the user, so the user will not be calling you at (in this case) restaurant closing time to tell them (the user) what to enter at each prompt.

Answer (score 1):

> The first line contains two numbers `n`,`m` satisfying `0 ≤ m ≤ n ≤ 1000`

That indicates to me that

```
int arr[100]={0};
```

is not sufficient for all test cases. Change it to:

```
int arr[1000]={0};
```

Comment: thnkx... now successfully submitted... :)